Hamburger Manu disappeared when switched to mobile view
Desktop View
Mobile View
My website is https://maradictionary.blogspot.com, based on blogger default theme (Simple Pale).
I created a Hamburger manu and search box on the same cross column, opposite to each other. My problem is, when i switched to mobile view, they are not seen.
I want them to be seen on mobile view. Please help me.
